# Passing argument to the build in Bamboo

Tags: java, maven, bamboo

I have a build in Bamboo using Maven. I need to pass two or more argument But I don't know how I do it. 
I can pass one argument by using 
`exec:java -Dexec.args=arg1`  and the arg1: the argument which is a String type.

also I can pass arguments through POM. But what I want is to pass arguments by Bamboo plan

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with Bamboo variables. All you need to do is to define a [global](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/defining-global-variables-289277112.html) or [plan variable](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/defining-plan-variables-289276859.html) and [run the plan manually](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/running-a-plan-build-manually-289276898.html) by choosing *Run > Run Customized* and choose **Override a variable** to choose another variable to override the following aspects of the plan.

[image]